# Pandas applying function to multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Applying a function on a list of dataframes, getting error "string indices must be integers, not str"

The function works fine when applied individually on each dataframe. However returns error when applied on a list of dataframes.

My data looks like below:

```
    data
     date center dt Cust Type
     2017-09-20 AA I
     2017-09-21 BB E
     2017-09-25 BB I
     2017-09-29 AA I
```

Function being applied:

```
def calc2(data):
    def naming(x_array):
        ww = ' '.join(str(n) for n in x_array)
        return(ww)
    dc = data['center'].unique()
    dt = data['dt'].unique()
    ct = data['Cust Type'].unique()
    key = [dc,dt,ct]
    key = map(naming,key)
    dc, dt, ct = key[0], key[1], key[2]
    date = data['date']
    print(dc,dt,ct,date)

   dfs = ['df1','df2','df3']
   map(calc2,dfs)
```

Error:

```
     ----> 6     dc = data['center'].unique()
           7     dt = data['dt'].unique()
           8     ct = data['Cust Type'].unique()

    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

While works fine on individual dataset:

```
    calc2(df1) -- works
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sure, Done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `list of dataframes` is not *actually* a list of dataframes. It is, in fact, a list of strings:

```
dfs = ['df1','df2','df3']

print(type(dfs[0])) # <class 'str'>
```

Make sure a list of dataframes is assigned to `dfs`. In addition, I recommend you have your function return values, rather than simply using `print`.